# I am trying to add multiple rows in access based on certain criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to MS Access and SQL Server and I am trying to learn them.

I have a table that lists certain products with components. There are 4 columns:

```
PNUM, Component_PNUM, WHS, quantity
```

I need to do a mass add in component_PNUM to each PNUM that ends with certain criteria. I can use the WHERE clause to filter the correct pnum, but I do not know how to do a mass add to the right products.

Comment: Are you trying to add the same value to each record? If not, what source is the new data coming from?

Comment: Almost, I need to add Pkg-788812 and Pkg-700200 to Component PNUM.  And I need to add to quantity 1 to Pkg-788812 and quantity 4 for Pkg-700200.

Comment: so you want to `Pkg-788812` and `Pkg-700200` to `component_PNUM` for all records?

Comment: Yes I need to add "Pkg-788812" and "Pkg-700200 to Component_PNUM and I need to add "1" and "4" to quantity for each component

Comment: _"do a mass add"_ means what: just for the purposes of a `select` query, or do you want to `update` the stored data permanently?

Comment: If you change your select query to an append query, I think you'll have what you want.  You'll have to pick a value for your quantity field for all of your new rows, unless you want to use the SWITCH or CHOOSE function, but if you're only adding two rows, you can just add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that will make the `[component_PNUM]` set to the value `Pkg-788812 Pkg-700200` and the `[quantity]` field set to `1 4`.

**Please note this query will change the data in your database permanently. Take a backup before running this.**

```
UPDATE table-name
SET [quantity] = '1 4', [component_PNUM] = 'Pkg-788812 Pkg-700200'
```

However I don't think that is what you are looking for. What this will do is set the `quantity` to all the same value (and this will not be represented as a numeric value). Also, `[component_PNUM]` will have the same value for all records.

Best practice is that for each column, there should only be one value for each record. This sounds like both columns will have two values. Also, `quantity` sounds like it should be a numeric value and in that case, you cannot add two values like 1 and 4. It can only be one numeric value.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.  The quantity 1 and 4 and the two pkg numbers need to be separate records.

Comment: Beth, I know I can't have two values on one record. The two values are actually two separate records.